# Crontab время выполнения в определенном радиусе (промежутке)

Tags: crontab

Искал в сети но так и на нашёл (может плохо искал). Подскажите как выполнять get каждый день в промежутке с 8 утра до 12 ночи (23:59 + 1 минута). Или же во всё время кроме промежутка с 12:01 ночи по 7:59 утра.

Comment: странное желание... в текущей формулировке ответ будет где-то между «невозможно» и «бессмысленное усложнение»...лучше уточнить [задачу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4900/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-yx)...

Comment: "может плохо искал" - вы бы помогли ответить на ваш вопрос, если бы вместо не информативной фразы указали ключевые слова, по которым вы искали.

Comment: *как выполнять get каждый день в промежутке* — как вы вообще представляете это алгоритмически? ну, для человека — понятно: 1. вспомнил про задачу. 2. если текущее время подходит, выполнил. // а для компьютера это как должно звучать?

Comment: *Или же во всё время кроме промежутка* — а это что вообще такое??? что это за «во всё время»???

Comment: @alexanderbarakin человек просто задал вопрос, к чему лишнее комментирование? Задача не выполнима - так и скажите. А к ТС: увы так нельзя, крон не работает по «гибкому графику».

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос про "запуск в промежутки времени каждый день", то могу предложить вариант со следующим списком crontab-ов.

запускаем каждую минуту в интервале 8 часов утра - 23 часа:

```
* 8-23 * * * /path/to/script
```

запускаем каждую минуту в интервале 23:00 - 23:59

```
0-59 23 * * * /path/to/script
```

и наконец запускаем в 0 часов:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script
```

Как это решить одной строчкой crontab-а я не знаю. Возможно кто-нибудь предложит более элегантное решение.

Comment: объеденить первые два варианта ) 0-59 8-23 * * * /path/to/script